# Problem with defining multiple modules in Angular typings.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Here is my `typings.d.ts` file from Angular 6 project:

```
import { Injectable, InjectableDecorator, HostBinding, HostBindingDecorator, HostListener, HostListenerDecorator } from '@angular/core';

// Those decorators are declared with `any` type by default. Because of that
// `no-unsafe-any` TSLint rule reports errors on for example `@Injectable`
// decorator. Below declarations fix that.
declare module '@angular/core' {
    export interface InjectableDecorator {
        (providedIn?: any | 'root' | null): ClassDecorator;
    }
    export const Injectable: InjectableDecorator;

    export interface HostBindingDecorator {
        (hostPropertyName?: string): PropertyDecorator;
    }
    export const HostBinding: HostBindingDecorator;

    export interface HostListenerDecorator {
        (eventName: string, args?: string[]): MethodDecorator;
    }
    export const HostListener: HostListenerDecorator;
}

// Allows to import JSON files inside TypeScript files
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

The last declaration for `'*.json` should allow me to import JSON files inside TypeScript files (more details [here](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79)). It doesn't work - TypeScript compiler reports an error when I'm importing JSON file:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/internationalization/build-time-translate-loader.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../assets/i18n/translations.json'
```

The weird thing is that as soon as I move `declare module '*.json' { ... }` part from `typings.d.ts` to any other `.d.ts` file, e.g. `json.d.ts` the compiler stops complaining and JSON is imported properly without errors. The same happens when I move out `declare module '@angular/core' { ... }` part to another file. It makes me assume the problem is in both declarations coexisting in a single file.

Contrary to that [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) states you can declare multiple modules in a single `.d.ts` file:

> We could define each module in its own .d.ts file with top-level export declarations, but it’s more convenient to write them as one larger .d.ts file. To do so, we use a construct similar to ambient namespaces, but we use the module keyword and the quoted name of the module which will be available to a later import. For example:
>
> ```
> declare module "url" {
>     export interface Url {
>         protocol?: string;
>         hostname?: string;
>         pathname?: string;
>     }
>
>     export function parse(urlStr: string, parseQueryString?, slashesDenoteHost?): Url;
> }
>
> declare module "path" {
>     export function normalize(p: string): string;
>     export function join(...paths: any[]): string;
>     export var sep: string;
> }
> ```

Which is exactly what I'm doing. Why it doesn't work, when both `declare module` are in the same file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typings.d.ts` is treated as an external module because it contains a top-level import.  Hence, every `declare module "..." { ... }` statement in the file is treated as a module augmentation, not an original declaration of a module.  The augmentation of `"*.json"` is discarded because no original declaration of `"*.json"` is available, and unfortunately you don't get an error when this happens in a `.d.ts` file; I'm unsure if there's a good reason for that.  Putting the `declare module "*.json"` in a file with no top-level imports is the correct solution.  Unfortunately, none of this is properly documented.